# How to stretch mp3 file from 1 hour to 12 hours straight?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

Not sure how to explain this...

I have an MP3 track that lasts 1 hour.

My phone app loop doesn't work well, so I want to repeat the same track over and over for 12 hours, so I want to copy it from itself and link it together in sequence in a long file.

Take a 1 hour track, duplicate it 12 times and save it in a single track.

I thought I could use VLC for that but open to any other options.

Comment: Anaksunaman, yes indeed your answer is the best, can you answer and I will vote it as the best one? I can't choose just a comment! Thanks;)

Comment: Added a concise answer (and yes, it is hard to choose comments). =)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Windows, you may want to have a look at [Merge MP3](https://www.shchuka.com/software/mergemp3/). It is a completely free program with a simple to use GUI interface which allows you to merge as many MP3 files as you like (in your case, multiple copies of your original file). It requires no installation (just unzip and run) and tends to be very quick with merges.

Importantly, it also takes care of some subtle technical details (especially with ID3 tags) that aren't necessarily handled in other programs or through other more basic methods of combination.

If this solution isn't suitable (for example, if you are on some Unix-like OS or you need a command-line utility), you might want to look at this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62618/what-is-the-best-way-to-merge-mp3-files) for more options.